# Selecting array of options as part of select statement

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join, group-concat

I have this 2 tables:

**Options**

```
id, name, created_at, ...
```

Options table have many sub-options

**SubOptions**

```
option_id, name, created_at, ....
```

I was wondering if this possible to retrieve all of the `SubOptions` as part of a query select on `OPTIONS` , by using join (or anything else?) when the OPTION is grouped.

For example:

```
Select * 
from Options 
JOIN SubOptions ON Options.id = SubOptions.option_id 
GROUP BY Options.name
```

Now i know i can access `SubOptions.name` , but is there any way to access *all* of `SubOptions`s with `option_id` equal to `option_id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**GROUP_CONCAT()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function to group sub option names

Try this:

```
SELECT O.name, GROUP_CONCAT(SO.name) subOptionName
FROM Options O 
LEFT JOIN SubOptions SO ON O.id = SO.option_id 
GROUP BY O.name;
```